# Any way to improve this slow query?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Its particular query pops up in the slow query log all the time for me. Any way to improve its efficiency?

```
SELECT 
    mov_id, 
    mov_title, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT genres.genre_name) as all_genres, 
    mov_desc, 
    mov_added, 
    mov_thumb, 
    mov_hits, 
    mov_numvotes, 
    mov_totalvote, 
    mov_imdb, 
    mov_release, 
    mov_type 
FROM movies 
LEFT JOIN _genres 
    ON movies.mov_id = _genres.gen_movieid
LEFT JOIN genres
    ON _genres.gen_catid = genres.grenre_id 
WHERE mov_status = 1 AND mov_incomplete = 0 AND mov_type = 1 
GROUP BY mov_id 
ORDER BY mov_added DESC 
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

My main concern is in regard to the group_concat function, which outputs a comma separated list of genres associated with the particular film, which I put through a for loop and make click-able links.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the genre names? If you can do with just the genre_id, you can eliminate the second join. (You can fill in the genre name later, in the UI, using a cache).

What indexes do you have?

You probably want

```
create index idx_movies on movies 
  (mov_added, mov_type, mov_status, mov_incomplete)
```

and most certainly the join index

```
create index ind_genres_movies on _genres
  (gen_mov_id, gen_cat_id)
```

Comment: I use  domain.com/genre/genre_name   url, so IDs are not necessary. 

and yes, I have those index.

Comment: Looking at your EXPLAIN output, you are accessing not only to top 20 movies, but 5988 of them. It is using an index only on status. Are you sure you have an index on mov_added+mov_type+mov_status+mov_incomplete?

Comment: Yup, I do. Im trying to figure out why its looking at the complete table... instead of just the first 20 items.

Comment: From memory limit is one of the last things that is done to the query i.e. it is computed and then limited.

Comment: @rezzif: do not know about MySQL, but Oracle could in this case do an INDEX SCAN DESC to just get the first 20 movies in order.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the output of EXPLAIN? i.e. put EXPLAIN in front of the SELECT and post the results.

I've had quite a few wins with using SELECT STRAIGHT JOIN and ordering the tables according to their size.

STRAIGHT JOIN stops mysql guess which order to join tables and does it in the order specified so if you use your smallest table first you can reduce the amount of rows being joined.

I'm assuming you have indexes on mov_id, gen_movieid, gen_catid and grenre_id?

Answer (score 0):

The 'using temporary, using filesort' is from the group concat distinct genres.genre_name.

Trying to get a distinct on a column without an index will cause a temp table to be used.
Try adding an index on genre_name column.